# How to access Windows accent color in html/css

Tags: html, css, windows, diacritics

Is there a way to get Windows accent color for use in html/css for IE, Chrome, Moz? Or at least one of those?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I don't think this is possible by only using html,css and js.

Comment: -moz-win-accentcolor - only works with firefox

Comment: @polmabri I'd post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on Firefox in css with `-moz-win-accentcolor`.

For example, if you were trying to make the background color of a div match the accent color, do:

> div {
>    background-color: -moz-win-accentcolor;
>   }

As far as I know, no other browser (aside from Firefox-based browsers) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but there systemcolors now:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/system-color

Beware that you may end up with white-on-white with Chrome's AccentColor/AccentColorText.